# mysql windows service stuck in starting state

Tags: mysql, windows, service, restart

Sometimes **Mysql57** service while restarting after config changes remains in starting state. most times after a while it comes back in **Started**. But some times its get stuck in Starting.
Even If I kill process and retry it, does not work.
What is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the service account you are using to run **Mysql57** service (you are logged in from that account, & Never use Network service account, Use an Admin account which has LOGON as service access, which comes when you just put the creds in for service account properties dialgue.)
2. Check the temp file which mysql is access does not have locks on it.
3. restart the machine and try again